# Laravel Argument 1 passed string given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So It is been 2 hours and I can't still get my app to work. I am getting the error exception `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ProgramController::index() must be an instance of App\User, string given`. Here is my route:

```
$app->bind('user', function($value, $route) {
    return User::findOrFail($value);
});

$app->get('program/profile/{user}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProgramController@index');
```

And in my controller:

```
public function index(User $user) {
    return view('auth.welcome', compact('user'));

}
```

Whenever I run something like `http://localhost:8000/program/profile/username`, I always get that error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public function index($username) {
    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();

    return view('auth.welcome', compact('user'));

}
```